# Is there a way to send a string to an IPC socket from the command line (FreeBSD/Darwin)?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, freebsd, darwin

In am on macOS (Darwin/FreeBSD) and I am using bash. I wonder if there is a simple way to send a string to an IPC socket from the command line just like ">>", maybe?

Comment: Maybe `nc` can help?

Comment: @arrowd — Unfortunately, it does not seem to work with IPC sockets, but thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25433538/1135424, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26781/53084